# How to disable Origin's "compatibility mode" warning?

Tags: origin

I am running Origin with "disabled desktop composition", it allows me to see second monitor when I play Battlefield 4 (I can't set this option on x64 executable). But when Origin starts it shows popup:

[image: Origin Compatibility Mode Pop0Up]

**How can I disable the pop-up *without* disabling compatibility mode?**

UPDATE:
Another reason to have compatibility mode: When I play Battlefield 4 after 5-10 minutes of starting game, windows show "Not enough resources - disable themes" popup. But it not remembers choice in this dialogues because BF4 has x64 executable file. I disable desktop composition in advance, so this dialog is not appearing during game.